# what is $\mathbb{D}^{-}$? Clarification of notation

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

I am reading an article [here](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10233317). I came across the notation $\mathbb{D}^{-}$, started from proposition 4.1(p.11 of the pdf). I understand that $\mathbb{D}$ is the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C},|z|<1\}$, which is already explained in the article. However I can't find the definition of $\mathbb{D}^{-}$, so I would like to know its meaning, especially if $\mathbb{D}^{-}$ contain 0 or not.

Comment: The proof of Proposition $4.1$ makes me think that $\mathbb{D}^- = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| \leq 1\}$.

Comment: So that $^-$ denotes "closure".  Makes sense.